# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Triggering mapper: 'mapped class User->user'. Original exception was: Class 'flaskblog.Post' is not mapped

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

This error happened when I tried to test my database from cmd using python interpreter. I didn't get errors when I created the tables, but seems like there are problems still.

The models are like this:

```
    class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique = True, nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True, nullable = False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False, default = 'default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable = False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref = 'author', lazy = True)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False, default = datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable = False)
```